# Place On Plane Script In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started learning AR development with unity using this YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lelX8GGh_S8). At some point in the tutorial, the creator added a script called "Place on Plane" to the AR Session Origin. He didn't write the script in the tutorial and it seems more like a Unity script but for some reason, I wasn't able to find it in my Unity and now I'm stuck. Please, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Script: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/main/Assets/Scripts/PlaceOnPlane.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the PackageManager for ARFoundation

[image]

you find

Samples available at
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples

which basically means: These are **not** included! If you want to use anything from there then download and import these samples into your project.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

In order to add "Place On Plane" script follow the steps below:

1. In the Inspector Panel (Right Hand Side) with AR Session Origin selected add
   a blank script
2. Name the script as "PlaceOnPlane" and open it in Visual Studio Code
3. Copy and Paste the code from the link below in Script using VS Code Editor
   *https://github.com/allinreality/PlaneTracking-ARFoundationUnity3D/blob/main/RequiredAssets/PlaceOnPlane.cs*
4. Save the script and it will update the Component in Inspector Panel that
   will allow you to add Visual and Prefab

Hope this helps - Thank you